# How to execute a transact in angularfire?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

The code I have is that it provides the documentation of firebase, it is something simple an increment:

```
let transaction = this.db.firestore.runTransaction(t => {

    return t.get(query)

    .then(doc => {

    // Add one person to the city population.

    // Note: this could be done without a transaction

    // by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()

    let newPopulation = doc.data().population + 1;

    t.update(query, {population: newPopulation});

    });

    }).then(result => {

    console.log('Transaction success!');

    }).catch(err => {

    console.log('Transaction failure:', err);

    });
```

But the query does not work,

Argument of type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>'.

Thank You

Comment: Not a full answer, but for atomic increments, there's no reason to use a transaction at all, since [firestore supports them natively](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html).

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to increase atomic values ​​is

```
const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

      const query = this.db.collection(nameOfCollection).doc(idDoc);

    query.update({ valIncrement:increment }  )
```